# Чому відбулася втрата відмінювання іменних (нечленних) прикметників?

Tags: історія-мови

При з'ясуванні етимології  прикметників часто натрапляла на інформацію, що в історії їх формування  відбулася втрата відмінювання іменних прикметників.

Ось, наприклад, у [Ступені порівняння прикметників](http://www.wikipage.com.ua/1x5fb8.html):

> В історії формування прикметників відбулося такі зміни: розмежування функцій іменних (нечленних) і займенникових (членних) прикметників; втрата відмінювання іменних прикметників.

Не можу знайти інформації, яка б пояснювала ці зміни. Адже, в українській  мові  збереглися залишки  іменних форм прикметників [Валентина Єрмак
ІСТОРИЧНИЙ КОМЕНТАР ДО ПРИКМЕТНИКА](http://dspace.pnpu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/6042/1/Ermak.pdf):

> варт, певен, жив, здоров, здавна, стиха і інші.